# Faster method of counting specified values from rows in large matrix in R

Tags: r

MC is a very large matrix, 1E6 rows (or more) and 500 columns.  I am trying to get the number of occurrences of the values 1 through 13 for each of the columns.  Sometimes the number of occurrences for one of these values will be zero.  I would like my final output to be a 300X13 matrix (or data frame) with these count values.  I am wondering if anyone can suggest a more efficient manner then what I currently have, which is the following:

```
MCct<-matrix(0,500,13)
for (j in 1:500){
for (i in 1:13){
MCct[j,i]<-length(which(MC[,j]==i))}}
```

I don't that table works, because I need to also know if zero occurrences occurred...I couldn't figure it out how to do that if it is possible.  And I am only somewhat familiar with apply, so maybe there is a method to use that...I haven't been successful in figuring that out yet.

Thanks for the help,
Vivien

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `sapply` (to iterate from 1 to 13) and `colSums` (to add up the columns of `j`):

```
MCct <- sapply(1:13, function(i) {
  colSums(MC == i)
})
```

Comment: You can also replace the call to the `apply` function by `colSums(MC==i)`, which I think is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a set of values you're interested in

```
set <- 1:4
n = length(set)
```

and you have a matrix that includes those values, and others

```
m <- matrix(sample(10, 120, TRUE), 12, 10)
```

Create a vector indicating the index in the set of each matching value

```
idx <- match(m, set)
```

then make the index unique to each column

```
idx <- idx + (col(m) - 1) * n
```

`idx` ranges from 1 (occurrences of the first set element in the first column) to `n * ncol(m)` (occurrence of the nth set element in the last column of m). Tabulate the unique values of `idx`

```
v <- tabulate(idx, nbin = n * ncol(m))
```

The first `n` elements of `v` summarize the number of times set elements 1..n appear in the first column of `m`. The second `n` elements of `v` summarize the number of times set elements 1..n appear in the second column of `m`, etc. Reshape as the desired matrix, where each row represents the corresponding member of the set.

```
matrix(v, ncol=ncol(m))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`table` can count zero occurrences, you just need to create a factor that has the whole range of levels, e.g.

```
apply(MC, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=1:13)))
```

This is not as efficient as @Patronus' solution though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!